# How do I add folder to Ubuntu 18.04.1 Nautilus Bookmark list?

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

How do I add folder to Ubuntu 18.04.1 Nautilus Bookmark list?

Ironically* I can do this via Open Project inside Eclipse, but Nautilus seems to give no option - not in right-click-menu, no Settings option, ...

(*) This is ironic as I cannot add Eclipse to the left hand Desktop Shortcuts - another problem with 18.04.1

Comment: dose it not work by just dragging the folder to the bookmark list?

Comment: Aha! But wait ... some do, some don't. e.g. I cannot add 'Computer' to it, which shows above Bookmarks on LHS with Ubuntu 12.04. Having to go into 'Other Locations' is a bit of a pain.

Comment: thank you for the certification and also is there a reason you are using Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Oops that should be Ubuntu 16.04, not 12.04. Although I do still use 12.04; a reason for still using it is that more recent versions do not support the older compilers, and the older compilers are needed for old legacy programs, and we want them to 'just work' without changing the source and environment, except for occasional feature tweaks.

Answer (score 25):

To add a folder to the bookmarks in Files (aka nautilus), either

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to add the folder you are currently in to the bookmarks list in the left pane (under the horizontal line separating the "special" folders, e.g. "Recent", "Home", etc.
- Drag a selected folder to the left pane.

You can see all defined hotkeys in Files when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl+D worked for me on 18.04.2 LTS.  Thanks!

Comment: It's worked(Ctrl + d) for me as well on 20.04 LTS. Thanks!